# Where are app preferences stored on mac ? (widgets/ toolboxes/ active menus positions)

Tags: macos, qt, widget, preferences

I have a Qt app that saves a number of settings, including its widgets and toolboxes positions, using an ini file. That allows for a easy restoring of defaults, just by removing the ini file... In windows and Linux.

In OSX (10.6-10.9), removing the ini file created by the app does not restore the toolbar positions to default. So I tried looking for other files... So far I found files created for the app in

```
/Users/Me/Library/Application Support/z.qhc         (a copy of the help database)
/Users/Me/Library/Preferences/com/x/y/Myapp.plist   (see contents below)

Root
    NSNavPanelExpandedStateForSaveMode  YES
    NSNavPanelExpandedSizeForSaveMode   (712, 448)
    NSNavLastRootDirectory              ~/x/y
    NSNavPanelExpandedSizeForOpenMode   (712, 448)
```

But after removing them, I still remember previous toolbox positions, as well as closed toolboxes.

Where else can I find such preferences/settings files for my app ? Where are the positions of widgets inside the app stored ?

Comment: [QSettings doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#platform-specific-notes) and [QStandardPaths doc](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qstandardpaths.html#StandardLocation-enum) include list of standard files locations on OSX.

Comment: Thank you for comment, the settings my app creates are using QSettings::IniFormat and placed in standard location. But seems mac writes additional settings elsewhere. Those locations are what I am looking for. The only locations I found info about are those I listed in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Application states, such as window positions are stored for each user in their Library folder.

Take a look in **/Users/Me/Library/Saved Application State**

Comment: I've got 2 instances of Yosemite and both include that folder. Check ~/Library/Saved Application State. You won't see the user's Library folder by default, but if you open a finder window, select "Go" from the dropdown menus and hold the 'Alt' key, it will show up in that menu

Comment: That is what I did... I am aware that these types of folders are in the /Users/current_user/Library/ folder, see my question... I simply do not have "Saved Application State" folder.  Thanks anyway